# if statement doesn't work in associtive array

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following problem. I am trying to write function that imports data from csv file. In this file in price column if there are sign like '<>' it means that price is in U.S. dollars and it needs to be converted. I understand that this variable is presented as a digit. How it could be converted to string? Or why the statement doesn't work at all? As always here is the source code.

```
$str='<>';
    if( $variant['price'] ==$variant['price'].$str)
    {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT rate_to FROM s_currencies WHERE id=1 LIMIT 0, 30 ");
  $course= mysql_fetch_row($sql);
//$rate=$course[0];
  $variant_price = $item['price']*$course[0];
  $variant['price']=$variant_price;
        }
```

Please help!

Comment: How can a string be equal to itself with two characters added to the end?

Comment: What does `$variant['price']` actually look like?

Comment: echo $variant['price'].' == '.$variant['price'].$str; what does this print?

Comment: Sorry I can't echo it because this cms built on MVC principal. This character is written in excel row and means dollar currency. How can I detect it if nessesery?

Comment: You can't tell us if it looks like `<>123`, `123<>`, `12<>34`?

Answer (score 3):

The code which you have posted will not enter into if condition. Make a check with code.

```
For eg. if $variant['price'] = '1';

if ('1' == '1<>')
{
}
```

The above condition will not enter into if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if that string exists, instead of using your current IF statement. [strpos](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php&ei=_7X3UaW_L4mK9QTLl4DICg&usg=AFQjCNEjKsouDlkL0hHbGLiLrM7Y9urQdQ&sig2=BeJbyv8wWdhfoI5SLV7_Iw&bvm=bv.49967636,d.eWU) will give you want you need

```
if(strpos($variant['price'],$str) !== false)  // <> is present
{
    // run your sql code
}
```

I'd also suggest getting away from the mysql_* functions as they're deprecated. Look into PDO or mysqli queries, with bound parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $str='<>';
   if( stristr($variant['price'],$str){
        $sql  ="SELECT rate_to FROM s_currencies WHERE id=1 LIMIT 0, 30 ";
         $qry = mysql_query($sql);
         if ($qry && mysql_num_rows($qry)>0){
            $variant['price'] = (str_replace($str,'',$variant['price'])*mysql_result($qry,0,0));
        } else {
            echo 'error while converting:' . mysql_error();
        }
   }
```

Comment: If `<>` is at the beginning of `$variant['price']`, `stristr()` will return `0`, which is `false`.

Comment: no it doesn't? <?
  $variant['price'] = '<>test';
  $str='<>';
  if( stristr($variant['price'],$str)){
   echo 'test';
  }
  ?>
echoes 'test'

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of `stripos()`.